How to convert sql file to db file for analysis using sqlite3 in python
I'm trying to analyze a wiktionary dump in sql using python sqlite3.  I'm just trying to output all the words that fall into certain categories, so once I get that list, I'm done with the sql file.  I don't have any experience with sqlite3 but have 10K hours of experience with Python.  I'm guessing I need to convert that sql file into a db file.  That's step 1.  I'll post step 2 as another thread. So my question is, how do I convert the sql file into a db file.  I see on the sqlite3 documentation that you can convert db into sql, but I can't find the other way around.
con = sqlite3.connect('existing_db.db')
with open('dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for line in con.iterdump():
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
con.close()

